# Webview issue, pdf links do not open, please assist

Tags: android-studio

Im trying open pdf`s from a selectable list with a wevbview but when I click in app nothing happens, I have given the app internet permision also read and write(tough not needed) to ext storage. Can anyone give me a hint?

I have tested the google docs version it works with it but there are login and print buttons there where they dont work in webview, and Id like users to save the pdf they pick to view

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            try{
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //user does not have a pdf viewer installed
            }
        } else {
            webview.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: Ok since I found a solution I will post it so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changed the code so instead of viewing in the webview it should just download the file. I still have no idea why the above code was not calling the default pdf viewer on the device.I had installed over 5 pdf viewers on my device and made at least 3 of them default to test - didnt work. So in the end I just changed the shouldOverrideUrlLoading to download the file in the ext storage and from then, the user can open it by any app he wants/has installed. Solution:

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

also added permissions to manifest to access the default download manager and external storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
```

this fixed it for me.